# Set focus on element in listElement

Tags: javascript, vaadin, shadow-dom

How can I set focus for the initial render? I cannot get access to the element this way. I use the same appcoach as in documentation but it doesnt work.
Maybe i have some mistake in my code

```
import {LitElement, html} from '@polymer/lit-element'
import {classMap} from 'lit-html/directives/class-map.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-text-field'

class ModalConfirm extends LitElement {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.opened = false;
        this.modalInputValue = '';
        this.textAreaId = 'myText';
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            opened: {type: Boolean},
            modalInputValue: {type: String},
            textAreaId: { type: String },
        }
    }


    firstUpdated() {
        const textArea = this.shadowRoot.getElementById(this.textAreaId);
        textArea.focus();
    }

    render() {
        return html`
<div class="dialog ${this.opened ? 'opened' : 'closed'}" >
    <p class="content">Enter new script name</p>
    <input
    id="${this.textAreaId}"
    value="${this.modalInputValue}" 
     @change="${this.onChange}">      
    </input>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="accept"  @click="${this.submitNewScript}">Ok</button>
      <button class="cancel" @click="${this.cancelChanges}">Cancel</button>    
    </div>
</div>`
    }
}

customElements.define('modal-confirm', ModalConfirm)
```

Comment: Do you mean `get focusButton() {...}`? Or `this.focusButton().focus();`

Comment: yes, I wanna get access to input and make it focus, but with ger doesnt work also

Comment: I solve my problem it was just firstUpdate dont work i use update instead

Answer (score 1):

consider also using `delegatesFocus` when creating the shadowRoot
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow

with LitElement override of `createRenderRoot` to set `shadowRoot` options as needed:

```
class ModalConfirm extends LitElement {
    createRenderRoot(){
        return this.attachShadow({
            mode: 'open',
            delegatesFocus: true
        });
    }
}
```